# Usage of “gauge”

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> His study has become a gauge of local attitudes and idiosyncrasies.

Based on my perception, the word “gauge” has to do with scaling. I checked this and I was right. Yes, it is about measuring.

Also, I know that this has to do with the unusual characteristics of the city Houston.

Answer (score 2):

> His study has become a gauge of local attitudes and idiosyncrasies.

“Gauge” (n.) means a measurement/estimate of something or a comparison of it to a known value.

So, as you assumed: “His study has become a [way to measure]. . .”

A way to measure what?

> . . .local attitudes and idiosyncrasies.

An idiosyncrasy is a unique, distinctive, or slightly unusual/uncommon behavior or habit of a person or place. So this is referring to the attitudes, behaviors, and features that make the city unique.

> His study has become a [way to measure the] local attitudes and [behaviors that make the city of Houston what it is].